# How to copy the matches block and write to another file using reqular expression on vim?

Tags: regex, macos, vim, copy-paste

i have set of `code` block in my file. I need to copy all the `code` block from that file and write to another file.

For example:

My current file content is:

CurrentFile.txt

````
* The method `make:` retrieves the prototype and clones it:

```cpp
make: partName
    ^ (partCatalog at: partName) copy
```

* The concrete factory has a method for adding parts to the catalog.

```cpp
    addPart: partTemplate named: partName
    partCatalog at: partName put: partTemplate
```

* Prototypes are added to the factory by identifying them with a symbol:

```cpp
    aFactory addPart: aPrototype named: #ACMEWidget
```
````

from my current file i need to copy only the code block and create another file, with out change my current file.

Expected output file is

OutputFile.cpp

```
make: partName
    ^ (partCatalog at: partName) copy


    addPart: partTemplate named: partName
    partCatalog at: partName put: partTemplate


    aFactory addPart: aPrototype named: #ACMEWidget
```

For matching my code block i used following regular expression on my vim
```` :%s/```cpp\n\(.*\n\)\{-}```//gc ````. Kindly help to solve my problem. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the ranges by the command

````
:g/^```cpp$/+1;/^```$/-1 w!>> filename
````

The result will not be exactly as you wrote in your example because the example contains extra blank lines that are not present in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of pcregrep (because normal grep doesn't support multiline matches).

````
pcregrep -Mo1 '```cpp\n((.|\n)*?)```' input.cpp > output.cpp
````

The above command would take your sourcecode from an file named input.cpp and would write the cleaned source to a file named output.cpp.

Explanation:

````
 //This matches the codeparts from your input file
 //whereby: -M is multiline, -o1 is first capturegroup => ((.|\n)*?)
 pcregrep -Mo1 '```cpp\n((.|\n)*?)```' input.cpp


 //This writes the cleaned text to output file
 > output.cpp
````